# VBA causing incorrect dates to be added to Access database

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
Private Sub Command16_Click()
 If Me.CurrentRecord < Me.Recordset.RecordCount Then
    DoCmd.GoToRecord Record:=acNext
 ElseIf Me.CurrentRecord = Me.Recordset.RecordCount Then
    Dim tempDate As Date
    tempDate = Me.Recordset!StartDate

    Me.Recordset.AddNew
    Me.Recordset!StartDate = DateAdd("d", 7, tempDate)
    Me.Recordset.Update
    Me.Recordset.MoveNext
 End If
End Sub
```

Using the code above causes my Access database table ("Weeks") to become corrupted.  For example, if I have:

```
2/5/2018
2/12/2018
```

Then I want the next button to result in:

```
2/5/2018
2/12/2018 
2/19/2018
```

Which 90% of the time it does; however, sometimes I end up with:

```
2/5/2018
2/12/2018
2/19/2018
2/12/2018 <-- WHY????
2/19/2018 <--- Obviously results from bug in the above line
```

Any idea why this is happening?  I assume it's something with the Recordset.  Seems to happen after I close the form and then open it back up.

Comment: what is the value of tempdate when this happens?

Comment: I will run it through the debugger in a couple minutes but it should be the last StartDate in the table.